# Flutter Streambuilder on new data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

im currently using a streambuilder to get my order data from firestore for a restaurant app and i want to make something when new order arrives, like a notification or something. How can i know if a new order added to database?

Comment: Just use StreamBuilder on top of your Firestore.instance.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).snapshots()

There is example in: https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore

Comment: And next time please provide your code and studies about question you ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to the stream you give in the "stream" field of your `StreamBuilder` and use that subscription created to call the `onData` property of `StreamSubscription`. It will call the function present inside it whenever new data is added.

Example:

```
Stream stream = <YOUR STREAM HERE>;
StreamSubscription streamSub;

String actionTaken(dynamic data){
    return data;
}

//call the code below in initState if you want to start it with the app.
streamSub = stream.listen(actionTaken);
subscription.onData((data){ 

});
```

Comment: You could probably print data from the onData call.